# Printing dictionary where the keys are static, and values dynamic in terminal

Tags: python, curses

I have a REST URL 
It returns a large JSON object as a dictionary.

```
{"id": 1, "name" : bobert, "cash" : 100}
```

I'm doing the basic print key, value, however here's the challenge:

I need it to look like this.

id   :  1
name :  bobert
cash :  100

^^^ I need the keys "(id, name, cash) to persist on the screen, and only the values (1, bobert, 100) to update with each new request.

This is similar to the problem of updating a single line like a progress bar, but for multiple lines.

```
for keys, values in my_resp.items():
  print ('  {}  =  {}  '.format(keys, values))
```

That code is the basic idea, but I need the keys to persist, and values to be updated.

I've looked at curses (which I think is too complicated for this)
And also looked the sys.stdout.write but that only appears to work for 1 line at a time.

Comment: You could use a [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) `\r` on each update, it simply returns to the beginning of the line, assuming I am understanding your desire correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what I use:

```
def printline(line):
    sys.stdout.write(line + "\x1b[K\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Call as `printline(string)`. Use a regular `print` statement to move to a new line. Otherwise, successive `printline` calls will overwrite the same line repeatedly, as you want. This works on UNIX-like terminals: the `\x1b[K` bit is an ANSI escape code which deletes to the end of the line, and the `\r` moves back to the start of the line (so the next `printline` will overwrite the current line).

Comment: This works for a single line. The OP wants to be able to update many lines at once. (Of course, obviously, updating many lines at once is just a matter of correctly addining newlines inside the printed string)

Answer (score -1):

Just add a newline:

```
for keys, values in my_resp.items():
  print ('  {}  =  {}  '.format(keys, values))
print "\n"
```

Comment: That will not accomplish what the OP wants at all, which is to be able to overwrite existing data on the screen.

Comment: ah, my apologies, one line in the question caused confusion. I'll leave this here as a reminder to comprehend completely before answering. I'd downvote my own answer if I could